# Prevent passing a temporary to a class that doesn't own it

Tags: c++, temporary

Is there a way in C++ to prevent passing a owning resource to something?

In particular, I'm thinking about a class that keeps pointers to external independent objects (the class is *not* the owner of these objects).

And I'm wondering: what's the best way to **enforce** the fact that this is not an owner?

In other words, how can I prevent a client from doing something like this:

```cpp
// my class
class NonOwner {
    T * m_p;
public:
    NonOwner(const T* p) : m_p(p) {}
    void DoStuffWithP() { // print m_p or whatever }
};

// client's code
NonOwner o{new T()}
// no! I would like to prevent this, because NonOwner doesn't own the pointer.
// It just keeps a weak reference to it (perhaps a weak_ptr?)
// and doesn't have any code to then free the memory (rightly so).
```

I would like instead to enforce a usage that is always like:

```cpp
auto t = new T(); // independent object. Someone owns this. Could be a unique_ptr
NonOwner o{t}; // ok, allowed.
```

Comment: `new` does'nt return a "temporary". I stays with you until you `delete` it

Comment: This is why raw pointers are discouraged.  There is no info in a bare pointer on where it comes from and who is responsible for cleaning it up.

Comment: @NathanOliver: this doesn't mean raw pointers are discouraged of course

Comment: One solution could be to ban `new` in your code base.  That would make a situation like this a lot less likely to happen.

Comment: Follow the policy of "raw pointers are non-owning pointer", and owning pointers are smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr`.  And never use `new` or `delete`, instead use `std::make_unique`.

Comment: [`std::experimental::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) might be used to show intended usage, even if not enforced.

Comment: Do you mean your class `NoOwner` doesn't want to manage the lifetime of the object?

Comment: Sorry @valdo. Perhaps temporary is the wrong term. Rvalue perhaps?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini: Replace temporary by owning ressources. unrelated to temporary or value category

Comment: @NathanOliver could there be a way for preventing the mistake (of passing something that has no owner), perhaps by only allowing constructors that take unique pointers? (And internally saving a weak ptr to it or something like that. And always checking whether that is valid every time is used).

Comment: @Eljay same question as the one I asked NathanOliver

Comment: @Nimrod yes, `NonOwner` doesn't manage the lifetime of the object. And I want to prevent accidentally passing an object that will leak because the client assumes that it instead becomes owned by `NonOwner`.

Comment: @Jarod42 What should I write instead of temporary? Rvalue? Independent (owned by someone else) object? Not sure what's the best term to express what I'm asking. (I hope what I'm asking is clear)

Comment: If you have a (smart) pointer that owns an object, and then something else holds onto a raw (non-owning) pointer to that object, then that object is destructed, and then the something else dereferences the now dangling non-owning raw pointer... that's a bug.  Don't do that.  As a crutch, you could use a `std::shared_ptr` and dole out `std::weak_ptr` to things.  That's a bandage for a bad design of ownership.  It'll work.  It'll get you by for the nonce.  But it is a foul code smell.  (There are legit uses of `std::shared_ptr`, but this more of an abuse of federated ownership.)

Comment: Let's make a more practical example. Perhaps it helps.
If I have a class that wants to use a particular instance of a behavior (that is some unique object that manages its own lifetime, and that I want to pass references of around). What would be the best architecture in this case?
Or perhaps a class that wants a read-only handle to a database, which I don't want to transfer the ownership of around.

Comment: The way to avoid holding onto a raw non-owning pointer that may become a dangling pointer is not to hold onto the pointer in the first place.  Have the object be passed to the member function as a parameter when needed, and have it passed by `T&` or `T const&` and not by `T*` or `T const*` unless `nullptr` is okay and expected/allowed.

Comment: @Eljay ok, I understand. Thank you. And in the case I want to memoize/cache this pointer? For example if my class is using this a lot (let's say I save the handle to a db upon creation, and then I do a lot of operations on it), then my options are either a) passing it along with every method call (parameter bloat), b) caching it but always checking if it's valid (error prone)? (Or perhaps c) is there some error in my design?)

Comment: I suspect this question can't be answered until there's agreement on what "owning" means.  It's suggested in the question that if two pointers, `t` and `o.m_p` point to the same object, `t` is "owning" and `o.m_p` is "not an owner".  How is this determined?

Comment: if a caller passes a raw non owning pointer to your class then the mistake is on the caller. You cannot possibly prevent a caller from writing wrong code. A raw pointer already indicates that the method does not participate in ownership, if thats not enough you cannot help someone who wants to use your class in the wrong way

Comment: If you want to memoize/cache the pointer, then you have to be very careful to ensure that the pointer is valid during the lifetime of the object that is holding that non-owning pointer.  If you cannot ensure that, or have to use elaborate machinations to ensure that, then you should not do that and instead pass the pointer in as a parameter for every time it needs to be used.  In my own code, "scoped classes" are ones that use a RAII pattern.  Those objects have limited scope, and are always used as automatic storage objects (and never dynamic objects).

Comment: Since your design is let the caller(or upper level) manage the life of the object. I don't really think it's a problem you need to consider. Users can still leak the memory if they forgot to delete the pointer. What you want is only to disallow a corner case which definitely leaks the memory.

Comment: @DrewDormann by "x is owned by y" I mean that y is responsible for deleting x at some point (e.g. x is a raw pointer and y is the unique_ptr that owns it and frees it upon destruction).

Comment: @Nimrod maybe the fact that I wrote `auto t = new T()` can be misleading. But assume that that's instead managed by `OwnerOfSomething o; // internally it has a ptr 't' to some dynamic memory, and manages it cleanly in RAII style`. My question is: is there a way to only allows things like `NonOwner n{o.t};` and disallow `NonOwner {new T()};`? I don't know, for example by having `NonOwner` only take unique_ptrs, or preventing it from taking rvalues or something along this lines. (Not sure if it's possible and by what means).

Comment: Rust is this way ---> https://www.rust-lang.org/ Seriously, there is only that much you can express with the relatively primitive C++ type system. Enforce complex conditions at code review time.

Comment: Gotcha. From my perspective, if you declare the parameter as a raw pointer, there is no way for it. Of course, you can force the user to pass a `unique_ptr` or something with RAII which will never leak here.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the link! I haven't used Rust but I know it's all based on tracking ownership. I would be interesting to know how much of Rust's behavior can be replicated in C++, even if it requires a complex solution (complex for the library write, but then easy not to mis-use for the client), and what instead can't be because of fundamental differences in how the languages work.

Comment: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-lifetime-safety

Answer (score 1):

You could try to pass a ref to the pointer. But as you cannot automatically convert a non const pointer to a const pointer ref, you need both overloads for const and non const (thanks to Jarod42 for that point):

```
class NonOwner {
    T * m_p;
public:
    NonOwner(const T*& p) : m_p(p) {}
    NonOwner(T*& p) : m_p(p) {}
    void DoStuffWithP() { // print m_p or whatever }
};
```

When you later try to use it, you correctly get:

```
NonOwner o( new T() ); // croaks for "cannot convert argument 1 from 'T *' to 'T *&'"
auto t = new T();
NonOwner o1(t);        // no error
```

What makes the compiler croak, is that the ref can only be binded to a lvalue what the result of an expression is not.

Comment: Very interesting! What's the underlying mechanism it relies on to "croak"? The fact that I can't have a reference to `new T()` because that expression evaluates to an rvalue?

Comment: @Jarod42: Sigh... Time for me to have a coffee... or maybe a stronger drink! How could I not realize that :-( . Thank you very much. I have edited my post...